# HOw to add combobox/dropdownbox in Action script 3 in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have searched a lot but could found  a code where i can add comobox on screen
CAn anyone give me example .
 like

```
Var combobox = new Combobox();
```

i don't have any gui

Where can i get the list/attributes of all the components like API for use in AS3

Comment: Are you building a Flex component "class Foo extends UIComponent {}", or just a Flash sprite?

Answer (score 0):

API is at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/ComboBox.html

Answer (score 0):

You're not being very clear with the question. If you want to add a ComboBox to the screen in AS3, your code works, except you need to attach it to something. e.g.,

```
var c:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
c.dataProvider = yourData;
someCanvas.addChild(c);
```

However, if you want to build your own `ComboBox` and have it pop up in a similar way, you're treading into more complicated land. The basics are that it's just a `TextInput` control where you use the `PopupManager` to show/hide a `List` object depending on the user action (e.g., click, typing, etc...). But you will run into lots of focus/event issues.

Take a look at the ComboBox source code in the Flex SDK.